# k8s vs docker in Geth operation

Tags: go-ethereum, docker, prysm

I'm trying to set up an infrastructure to load balance multiple Ethereum nodes and serve them as a single RPC endpoint.

Assuming this configuration, I thought it would be efficient to run multiple geth and prysm on k8s.

However, I understand that currently you have to connect one prysm to one geth (I may be wrong about this), and I was wondering if it is possible to connect one prysm to multiple geths.
(If anyone has tried this, it would be great to know how).

Also, assuming you are running multiple geths + prysm, it would be great if you could share your experience on whether k8s or docker compose is more efficient.

I realize that many of you have a lot of experience running nodes, so we're asking for your help:)